# SSH with Command Doesn't Run as an Alias

Tags: shell, ssh, quoting, alias, function

I have the following command to remote into a local server and `tail -f` the latest log file for an application that I have.

The command works perfectly fine from the command line -

`ssh user@hostname 'tail -f $(ls -1r ~/Development/python/twitter-bot/logs/*.log | head -1)'`

The problem is that when I make it an alias (or even a function), it evaluates the completion of the `ls -1r` on my local machine and tries to pass that to the remote machine.

```
alias latestbotlogs="ssh user@hostname 'tail -f $(ls -1r ~/Development/python/twitter-bot/logs/*.log | head -1)'"

function latestbotlogs {
    ssh user@hostname 'tail -f $(ls -1r ~/Development/python/twitter-bot/logs/*.log | head -1)'
}
```

What syntax do I need to use such that the entire command gets evaluated on the remote machine that I am accessing via SSH.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the alias you need some escapes

```
alias latestbotlogs="ssh user@hostname 'tail -f \\\$\\(ls -1r \\~/Development/python/twitter-bot/logs/*.log \\| head -1\\)'"
```

or

```
alias latestbotlogs='ssh user@hostname '\''tail -f $(ls -1r ~/Development/python/twitter-bot/logs/*.log | head -1)'\'
```

The second version is easier, you don't have to think about all the operators you have to quote.

The function should work as it is.

Comment: The second one worked - didn't realize there were different escape characters in `alias` commands. Thanks so much!

Comment: It's not different escape characters in the `alias` command, it's that you need to quote or escape once to assign the alias and have enough quotes or escapes left for the actual command.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to getting the somewhat complicated quote-escaping right:

```
 alias botlogs='ssh user@host "ls -r ~/whatever/*log | head -1 | xargs tail -f"'
 # if (selected) filename contains backslash or quotemark(s) 
 # need -d'\n' on GNU and I don't know good solution on other
 # this also fails if filename contains whitespace, but so did $( )
```

although I concur that the function should work without any hackery and in general functions are more consistent and flexible and just plain better than aliases.

And PS: when `ls` output is piped (or redirected) it always uses 1-column format, you don't need `-1` here.

Comment: This is a great alternative solution as well (and is much easier to read). I always forget about `xargs` & good to know about the `ls` piped - thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You may set the alias by assigning a string wrapped in single quotes to `latestbotlogs`, as in:

```sh
alias latestbotlogs='ssh user@hostname '\''tail -f $(ls -1r ~/Development/python/twitter-bot/logs/*.log | head -1)'\'
```

where the expression `\'` is used to protect single quotes from the shell and have them concatenated in the resulting command. You can verify that they are preserved:

```sh
$ alias latestbotlogs
alias latestbotlogs='ssh user@hostname '\''tail -f $(ls -1r ~/Development/python/twitter-bot/logs/*.log | head -1)'\'''
```

While with your alias:

```sh
alias latestbotlogs="ssh user@hostname 'tail -f $(ls -1r ~/Development/python/twitter-bot/logs/*.log | head -1)'"
```

the command substitution is evaluated immediately, upon definition. This happens because single quotes lose their special meaning when escaped (with `\`) or enclosed in double quotes (`"`). (Reference: [Quoting](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02) in "The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7, 2018 edition").
And this is the key: single quotes around the remote command are enough to protect it when the alias is *invoked*, but do not prevent the enclosed command to be substituted when the alias is *created*.

You can also use `"'"` as an alternative to `\'`:

```sh
alias latestbotlogs='ssh user@hostname '"'"'tail -f $(ls -1r ~/Development/python/twitter-bot/logs/*.log | head -1)'"'"
```

Or enclose the whole command in double quotes and add some escaping:

```sh
alias latestbotlogs="ssh user@hostname 'tail -f \$(ls -1r ~/Development/python/twitter-bot/logs/*.log | head -1)'"
```

In this last form, all the characters that retain a special meaning when double-quoted (`$`, `` ` `` and `\`) have to be escaped (here we have only a `$`).

Your function, instead, should just work.